# What is the difference between hf.Registrar.Roles and hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles in the Fabric CA?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

As far as I understand the `hf.Registrar.Roles` attribute defines the roles that the identity I'm creating can register when this identity in-turn registers new identities. What does the `hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles` attribute define? Any research online leads me to believe it performs the same fucntion as what the `hf.Registrar.Roles` attribute does. If someone can point out the difference between the two and explicate how they both make a difference in a practical scenario, it would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add an answer below, but if you go to https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html?highlight=delegate#registering-a-new-identity and scroll down you'll find a table which explains the various attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hf.Registrar.Roles** - these are the roles which the registrar is allowed to assign to users it registers

**hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles** - these are the roles which the registrar is allowed to assign to the *hf.Registrar.Roles* attribute of users it registers

For example, the "super" admin may want to register a user which is also allowed to register users but may want to restrict that user from creating additional registrars or may want to limit the roles it can create registrars for.

So let's say *hf.Registrar.Roles="client,user,peer"* but *hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles="client"*.  This means the registrar can register users with roles client,user or peer but can only create additional registrars with the attribute *hf.Registrar.Roles="client"*.